# How to get value from request variable by key (Request[key]) using moq for mocking

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, moq, httphandler, http-request-parameters

I am using moq for unit testing an ASP.NET Http Handler.

Here I am trying to access the HttpRequest instance for the current request by using the Request property of the HttpRequestBase class.
As we know simplified syntax can be used for accessing data from the QueryString, Form, Cookies, or ServerVariables collections i.e. Request["key"]. (Which is being used in the ProcessRequest method of handler)

But I am not able to get the querystring value. Code is as follows:

Test class

```
    [TestMethod()]
    private static void MockProcessRequestExecution(AbcHandler abcHandler)
    {       
        NameValueCollection queryString = new NameValueCollection();
        queryString.Add("employeeid", "22"); 

        Mock<HttpContextBase> testHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        Mock<HttpResponseBase> testHttpResponse = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        Mock<HttpRequestBase> testHttpRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();

        testHttpContext.SetupGet(context => context.Response).Returns(testHttpResponse.Object);
        testHttpContext.SetupGet(context => context.Request).Returns(testHttpRequest.Object);
        testHttpRequest.SetupGet(request => request.QueryString).Returns(queryString);            

        testHttpContext.SetupGet(context => context.Request.QueryString).Returns(queryString);

        testHttpResponse.SetupSet(response => response.ContentType = "text/plain");

        abcHandler.ProcessRequest(testHttpContext.Object);

        testHttpResponse.VerifyAll();   
    }
```

Inside the handler method code is extracting request variable as following:

```
    ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        var employee = context.Request["employeeid"];
    }
```

The value of employeeid is coming as null.

I am getting the value if it written as context.Request.QueryString["employeeid"], but the code written in the ProcessRequest method can not be changed.
So the question is, how to get the value of Request key: "employeeid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses the Request [Item property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item(v=vs.110).aspx) which does not only look at the query string. From msdn:

> Gets the specified object from the QueryString, Form, Cookies, or ServerVariables collections.

As you are mocking the Request object, you will need to mock the Item property as well, which is what your code uses. (The code in the real `HttpRequest` class that looks at the QueryString property is not executed, since you are using a mock and not the real object!)

Unfortunately, you need to manually setup the Item property in the mock for every key, as in:

```
testHttpRequest.SetupGet(r => r["employeeid"]).Returns("22");
```

You could still create a `NameValueCollection` in your unit test and use a loop to setup the Item property for each key in the query string. This would also allow you to test code that uses both `Request["employeeid"]` and `Request.QueryString["employeeid"]` (which would return the same values).

```
NameValueCollection queryString = new NameValueCollection{ {"employeeid", "22"} };
//Setup Request Item property for each key in the query string
foreach (var qsKey in queryString.AllKeys)
{
    var key = qsKey;
    testHttpRequest.SetupGet(r => r[key]).Returns(queryString[key]);    
}
//You can still mock the Request.QueryString using the same values
testHttpRequest.SetupGet(r => r.QueryString).Returns(queryString);
```

Comment: Instead of:
'testHttpRequest.SetupGet(r => r[key]).Returns(queryString[key]);'  
I used:
'testHttpContext.SetupGet(context => context.Request[crKey]).Returns(queryString[crKey]);'

working fine! Thanks @Daniel

Comment: That should be fine too. Glad to be of help!